# Issue when trying to display data from MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database on PHPMyAdmin, named mydb, then a table named myguests. Its supposed to access the information on the database and display it. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('mydb');

$query = "SELECT * FROM myguests";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"].;
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

When I go to display the webpage it says

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\printback.php on line 10
```

Anyone have a solution?

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: You have an additional `.` at the end of your `echo "Name: " ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
echo "Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"].;
```

Has a dot right before the semicolon. Remove it and it'll work.

Comment: Thanks you for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .(dot) sign after $row["lastname"]

```
// Creates a loop to loop through results
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
    echo "Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"];
}
```